# SCSS for Loops - To generate shorter/combined code

Tags: css, loops, sass

I want to Generate combined/shorter CSS code using SCSS for loop. 
I'm using Dreamweaver2019 by the way but I don't  think its the problem.

I have tried the following:

1) This generates an error:

```
@for $i from 1 to 6 {
  #slide#{$i}:checked ~ #slide-btn label:nth-of-type(#{$i}) a
    &: { 
      background: none;
      height: 5px;
      width: 5px;
      border: solid 2px;
      border-color: #fff;
}
```

```
@for $i from 1 to 6 {
  #slide#{$i}:checked ~ #slide-btn label:nth-of-type(#{$i}) a
    & { 
    background: none;
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    border: solid 2px;
    border-color: #fff;
}
```

2) This produces a separate class/block:

```
@for $i from 1 to 6 {
  #slide#{$i}:checked ~ #slide-btn label:nth-of-type(#{$i}) a { 
    background: none;
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    border: solid 2px;
    border-color: #fff;
}
```

3)This will generate the closest to the desired result but I don't need extra class(.x) on my code.

```
@for $i from 1 to 6 {
  #slide#{$i}:checked ~ #slide-btn label:nth-of-type(#{$i}) a { 
       @extend .x
}
    .x {
    background: none;
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    border: solid 2px;
    border-color: #fff;
}
```

I expect a shorter SASS/SCSS code to produce exactly like this:

```
#slide1:checked ~ #slide-btn label:nth-of-type(1) a,
#slide2:checked ~ #slide-btn label:nth-of-type(2) a,
#slide3:checked ~ #slide-btn label:nth-of-type(3) a,
#slide4:checked ~ #slide-btn label:nth-of-type(4) a,
#slide5:checked ~ #slide-btn label:nth-of-type(5) a {
   background: none;
   height: 5px;
   width: 5px;
   border: solid 2px;
   border-color: #fff;
}
```

THANK YOU VERY MUCH to who ever can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO;

```
%x{
  background: none;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-color: #fff;
}

@for $i from 1 to 6 {
  #slide#{$i}:checked ~ #slide-btn label:nth-of-type(#{$i}) a { @extend %x }}
```

**output**;

```
#slide1:checked ~ #slide-btn label:nth-of-type(1) a,
#slide2:checked ~ #slide-btn label:nth-of-type(2) a, 
#slide3:checked ~ #slide-btn label:nth-of-type(3) a,
#slide4:checked ~ #slide-btn label:nth-of-type(4) a,
#slide5:checked ~ #slide-btn label:nth-of-type(5) a {
  background: none;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  border: solid 2px;
  border-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This work as I expected. Thank you Sir Chris W.